# In laravel 9 Can we pass single id of post with auth and on blade can we use that post id for two form submission?

Tags: laravel

I have a multiple post on frontend page , like is 1,2...7,8,9 and so on, and clicking on any id that should ask first for auth that i have done, now i have two form that are submitted for different columns with their own table and have 2 method, so questions is can we use single id and pass to two different forms?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your text, you want to execute 2 forms simultaneously on the `blade` side with the user's click.

I answer with this assumption.

We cannot run 2 forms in the blade at the same time.

It is not logical.

You submit a form that requires authentication.
For example:

```php
Route::get('my-form', FormController::class)->name('my-form');
```

```php
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        // First changes
        // Second changes

        return back();
    }
```

Then, when the user clicks, send the request to the form and make the changes related to both forms at the same time on the back-end side.

If your question is different. Be sure to let me know.